# bash script copy multiple folders and files logic

Tags: bash, subdirectory, batch-rename, file-copying

Bash Script:
Each file inside table directories will need be renamed from keyspace to newkyespace_456 when it is copied to destination.

```
└── Main_folder
    ├── keyspace
    │   ├── tableA-12323/keyspace-tableA-12323-ka-1-Data.db
    │   ├── tableB-123425/keyspace-tableA-123425-ka-1-Data.db
    │   └── tableC-12342/keyspace-tableA-12342-ka-1-Data.db
    └── newkeyspace_456 ( given folder) and sub folders
        ├── tableA-12523 
        ├── tableB-173425
        └── tableC-1242
```

Example is 
`keyspace/tableA-12323/keyspace-tableA-12323-ka-1-Data.db`
to
`newkeyspace_456/tableA-12523/newkeyspace_456-tableA-12523-ka-1-Data.db`

Note that same table (Type A , B , C) type can be copied to same table type in other keyspaces  (Type A , B , C) . The table name also need changes in  file name , please note in example 12323 has been renamed to 12523 when copied to diretory  newkeyspace_456/tableA-12523.

Type A table files can be copied from keyspace/tableA-12323 to Type A table files in newkeyspace_456/tableA-12523.

How do I approach this problem?

Thanks
tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use parameter expansion with string substitution for changing filename, like this:

```
for fn in $(find ./keyspace -path '*.db') ; do cp "$fn" "${fn//keyspace/newkeyspace_456}" ; done ;
```